# Updating Angular from 9 to 16, checking if all the config files are correct

Tags: angular

I've got an Angular 9 application that is using Material and we decided to update to Angular 16. Over the years the application has been developed by different people and the config files seem a little bit "confusing" I was wondering if there's a tool or something that tells me if everything is at its best or in compatibility mode.

For example, from building logs it seems that Ivy is correctly running, but I don't know if they're old config settings inside that prevent the application to run at its best.

For example, that's my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "types": [
      "node"
    ],
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "paths": {
      "@ttgdomain/*": [
        "src/app/domain/*"
      ],
      "@ttgshared/*": [
        "src/app/shared/*"
      ],
      "@ttgenvironments/*": [
        "src/environments/*"
      ],
      "@ttgservices/*": [
        "src/app/services/*"
      ],
      "@ttgpartials/*": [
        "src/app/partials/*"
      ],
      "@ttgauth/*": [
        "src/app/auth/*"
      ]
    },
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Another option I took is to create a new Angular 16 project, copy the application files then understand what is not correctly working. In this case I'm sure I am running at it's best.

Comment: You can use https://update.angular.io/ for an update guide. `ng update` will mostly automatically set up the config files for you. But, also, skipping versions makes the update a lot harder. Going version by version is the prefered way of doing it.

Comment: That 's what I have used, this guide, but I'm afraid that something weird remains ...and a tool that checks would have been great!

Answer (score 1):

To view the config files I used [angular-cli-diff](https://github.com/cexbrayat/angular-cli-diff) which allows you to see file changes between versions.